# Scala: the verification of correctness code example not working

Tags: scala, functional-programming, substitution, verification

I am reading now `Functional and Reactive Domain Modeling`. In the section 1.5, pg 30, there is an example:

```
credit(a, 100).flatMap(debit(_, 100))
=> Success(a.copy(balance = Balance(0 + 100))).flatMap(debit(_, 100))
=> debit(Account("a1", "John", .., Balance(100)), 100)
=> Success(a.copy(balance = Balance(100 - 100)))
=> Success(Account("a1", "John", .., Balance(0)))
```

I understand in general, what we do here: we substitute the functions with its implementations, for both `credit` and `debit` operations. In order to get finally the original result. But the exact example does not work.

For instance, with unit tests we use assertion to make sure it works. And as a result, to verify code, I can write expression and compare it. Here   is a strange syntax. What does "=>" mean? There is no any comparison. How would you verify the correctness

Here is a full example of the code before this verification to be able to run it:

```
import java.util.{ Date, Calendar }
import scala.util.{ Try, Success, Failure }
def today = Calendar.getInstance.getTime
type Amount = BigDecimal
case class Balance(amount: Amount = 0)
case class Account(no: String, name: String,
  dateOfOpening: Date, balance: Balance = Balance())

trait AccountService {
  def debit(a: Account, amount: Amount): Try[Account] = {
    if (a.balance.amount < amount)
      Failure(new Exception("Insufficient balance in account"))
    else Success(a.copy(balance = Balance(a.balance.amount – amount)))
  }
  def credit(a: Account, amount: Amount): Try[Account] =
    Success(a.copy(balance = Balance(a.balance.amount + amount)))
}

object AccountService extends AccountService
import AccountService._

val t = today
val a = Account("a1", "John", t)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably know the `=>` is used in Scala for `Function` types: `A => B` is an alias for `Function[A, B]`.

But in non-Scala context it sometimes appear in e.g. REPLs before printed expression result. I guess it is exactly, what we have here, except it also shows partial results (which is weird itself, as I haven't seen any REPL do it).

```
credit(a, 100).flatMap(debit(_, 100))
=> Success(a.copy(balance = Balance(0 + 100))).flatMap(debit(_, 100))
   // credit substituted with its result
=> debit(Account("a1", "John", .., Balance(100)), 100)
=> Success(a.copy(balance = Balance(100 - 100)))
   // debit substitutes with its result
=> Success(Account("a1", "John", .., Balance(0)))
   // final result
```

For me it is a bit inconsistent/confusing notation for explaining referential transparency and/or how we arrived at the final result.

As for testing the result with assertion, in the end you get `Try[Account]`. Even without any test framework matchers you could could check it as:

```
// given
val credit = credit(a, 100)

// when
val result = credit.flatMap(debit(_, 100))

// then
assert( result == Success(Account("a1", "John", .., Balance(0))) )
```

With e.g. ScalaTest assertion would look like

```
result shouldBe Success(Account("a1", "John", .., Balance(0)))
```

while Specs2 have something even more specific

```
result must beSuccessfulTry.withValue( Account("a1", "John", .., Balance(0)) )
```

(They all check basically the same thing, the difference will be report format on test failure.)